# Data structure for inverting a subarray in log(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Build a Data structure that has functions:

**`set(arr,n)`** - initialize the structure with array `arr` of length `n`. Time `O(n)`

**`fetch(i)`** - fetch `arr[i]`. Time `O(log(n))`

**`invert(k,j)`** - (when `0 <= k <= j <= n`) inverts the sub-array `[k,j]`. meaning `[4,7,2,8,5,4]` with `invert(2,5)` becomes `[4,7,4,5,8,2]`. Time `O(log(n))`

How about saving the indices in binary search tree and using a flag saying the index is inverted? But if I do more than 1 invert, it mess it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we can approach designing such a data structure.
Indeed, using a balanced binary search tree is a good idea to start.

First, let us store array elements as pairs `(index, value)`.
Naturally, the elements are sorted by index, so that the in-order traversal of a tree will yield the array in its original order.

Now, if we maintain a balanced binary search tree, and store the size of the subtree in each node, we can already do **fetch** in `O(log n)`.

Next, let us only *pretend* we store the index.
Instead, we still arrange elements as we did with `(index, value)` pairs, but store only the value.
The `index` is now stored *implicitly* and can be calculated as follows.
Start from the root and go down to the target node.
Whenever we move to a left subtree, the `index` does not change.
When moving to a right subtree, add the size of the left subtree plus one (the size of the current vertex) to the `index`.

What we got at this point is a fixed-length array stored in a balanced binary search tree. It takes `O(log n)` to access (read or write) any element, as opposed to `O(1)` for a plain fixed-length array, so it is about time to get some benefit for all the trouble.

The next step is to devise a way to **split** our array into left and right parts in `O(log n)` given the required size of the left part, and **merge** two arrays by concatenation.
This step introduces dependency on our choice of the balanced binary search tree.
[Treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) is the obvious candidate since it is built on top of the **split** and **merge** primitives, so this improvement comes for free.
Perhaps it is also possible to split a [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or a [Splay tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) in `O(log n)` (though I admit I didn't try to figure out the details myself).

Right now, the structure is already more powerful than an array: it allows splitting and concatenation of "arrays" in `O(log n)`, although element access is as slow as `O(log n)` too.
Note that this would not be possible if we still stored `index` explicitly at this point, since indices would be broken in the right part of a **split** or **merge** operation.

Finally, it is time to introduce the **invert** operation.
Let us store a flag in each node to signal whether the whole subtree of this node has to be inverted.
This flag will be lazily propagating: *whenever* we access a node, before doing anything, check if the flag is `true`.
If this is the case, swap the left and right subtrees, *toggle* (`true <-> false`) the flag in the root nodes of both subtrees, and set the flag in the current node to `false`.

Now, when we want to invert a subarray:

- split the array into three parts (before the subarray, the subarray itself, and after the subarray) by two **split** operations,
- *toggle* (`true <-> false`) the flag in the root of the middle (subarray) part,
- then merge the three parts back in their original order by two **merge** operations.

Comment: As far as I understand, the _search tree_ property is never used (and is actually broken after swapping the children nodes. All we need is _self-balancing_ binary trees?

Comment: @Antoine The structure is an implicit search tree. If we somehow stored and maintained the indices, the structure would be a search tree on these indices as keys. We do not store them, because they are hard to maintain. Nevertheless, we can say the array indices are keys in our binary search tree.